# Proof for left adjoint of $\lceil -/3 \rceil$

Tags: category-theory, galois-theory

The question 1.95 in [Fong](https://math.mit.edu/%7Edspivak/teaching/sp18/7Sketches.pdf) (1.01 in the PDF linked) is: whether $\lceil -/3 \rceil$ has a left adjoint $L: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$

The solution given is:

> Let's suppose we have a monotone map $L: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ that's left adjoint to $\lceil -/3 \rceil$ and see what happens.

> Writing $C(r) := \lceil r/3 \rceil$, then for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $L(z) \leq r$ iff $z \leq C(r)$ by definition of adjunction.

> So take $z = 1$ and $r = 0.01$; then $\lceil r/3 \rceil = 1$ so $z \leq C(r)$, and hence $L(z) \leq r$, i.e. $L(1) \leq 0.01$.

> In the same way $L(1) \leq r$ for all $r > 0$, so $L(1) \leq 0$.

> By definition of adjunction $1 \leq C(0) = \lceil 0/3 \rceil = 0$, a contradiction.

I don't get where this relation comes from from: "$L(1) \leq r$ for all $r > 0$"

Answer (score 1):

"the same way" mentioned here is what was just done with $r = 0.01$. Nothing specific was used about that number other than that its floor was at least one. You can use the same technique of setting $z$ and $r$ to something specific in the relation $L(z) \leq r$ iff $z \leq C(r)$. What could you set them equal to that would say something about $L(1) \leq r$?

**Spoilers below**

---

$L(1) \leq r$ iff $1 \leq C(r)$. For $r > 0$, $r/3 > 0$ too, so C(r) = $\lceil r/3 \rceil$ is at least 1. I.e., $1 \leq C(r)$. So $L(1) \leq r$ too.